# why does removing blank space while writing into file fails reading files?

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm learning C++, I find problems reading a file if I didn't add blank space while writing into it.

Plus, the file I wrote into doesn't contain blank space as intended.(I opened it with notepad++)

Btw, I'm using code::blocks17.12.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   ofstream out("file1");
    int i;
    ifstream in;
    if(!out){cerr << "create file error!\n"; return 1;}
    for(i = 1; i<=10; ++i) out << i <<' '; 
/*if I remove (<<' ') here, nothing was pirnted on screen. */
    out.close();

    in.open("file1");
    if(!in){cerr << "open file error!\n"; return 1;}
    while(in >> i) cout<< i << ' ';
    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `1`, `3` and `8` to a file without spaces then you get `138` how do you now want to figure out that it was not `138` that was written?

The input stream needs some kind of indication of how the numbers are separated.

If you want to know why they decided that writing a number does not automatically add a space, that is because it is not always the desired behavior.

And as [Martin Heralecký](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4005175)  correctly mentions. `in >> i` does not read in anything because without spaces `12345678910` is written to the file, which is most certainly out of the range of an `int` only your setup.

The actual size of an `int` is platform-dependent but you should not expect that it can store numbers larger than `2147483647`.

More details about the [Fundamental types: Properties](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties)

Comment: More interesting is the fact that nothing actually gets printed. After write, the file contains 12345678910, which is a valid number. However, it is so large that `int` is not enough and so `in >> i` doesn't work. Change `int` to `long long` and you should get printed at least the one big number as a whole.

Comment: I understand. what I meant to ask is the code without the blank space should print '12345678910' on the screen but there's nothing.

Comment: @EvanTaubenfeld I updated the answer according to the comment of `Martin Heralecký`. The problem is that `12345678910` is most certainly larger then what a `int` can store on your system. The maximum positive number of an `int` on your system is most certainly `2147483647`

Comment: I tried with long long int and it worked. Thanks a lot. @MartinHeralecký